# Getting an attribute value from XBRL file using XPath

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xbrl

I have this xbrl.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xbrli:xbrl xml:lang="nl" xmlns:bd-i="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/nt15/bd/20201209/dictionary/bd-data" xmlns:link="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:iso4217="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/iso4217" xmlns:xbrli="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance">
    <link:schemaRef xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://www.nltaxonomie.nl/nt15/bd/20201209/entrypoints/bd-rpt-ob-aangifte-2021.xsd"/>
    <xbrli:unit id="EUR">
        <xbrli:measure>iso4217:EUR</xbrli:measure>
    </xbrli:unit>
</xbrli:xbrl>
```

and I want to get the value of **xmlns:link** attribute.

This the code that I am using:

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import javax.xml.namespace.NamespaceContext;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            documentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);

            DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

            Document xmlDocument = documentBuilder.parse("src/resources/xbrl.xml");

            XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();

            final String namespace = "http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance";

            XPath xPath = xPathFactory.newXPath();
            xPath.setNamespaceContext(new NamespaceContext() {   
                public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
                    if (prefix.equals("xbrli")) {
                        return namespace;
                    } else {
                        return null;
                    }
                }

                public String getPrefix(String namespaceURI) {
                    return null;
                }

                public Iterator<String> getPrefixes(String namespaceURI) {
                    return null;
                }
            });
            String expression = "//xmlns:xlink";
            XPathExpression xPathExpression = xPath.compile(expression);
            Object result = xPathExpression.evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
            NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) result;
            if (nodeList.getLength() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                    System.out.println("[" + i + "]-1-NodeValue: " + nodeList.item(i).getNodeValue());
                    System.out.println("[" + i + "]-2-NodeName: " + nodeList.item(i).getNodeName());
                    System.out.println("[" + i + "]-3-TextContent: " + nodeList.item(i).getTextContent());
                    System.out.println("[" + i + "]-4-LocalName: " + nodeList.item(i).getLocalName());
                    System.out.println("[" + i + "]-5-NamespaceURI: " + nodeList.item(i).getNamespaceURI());
                }
                System.out.println("Printed nodes");
            } else {
                System.out.println("I got nothing");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("MESSAGE: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

The result is :(

I got nothing.

If I tried to get the value of another attribute of the XBRLfile, I can get it without any issues. But If I tried to get the value that i mentioned above then I get no thing.

This is a photo of my Intellij:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ta3cE.png)

Why I can not get the value of the attribute?

Comment: The xpath could be perhaps `//@xlink:type`

Comment: I tried //@xlink:type but it dose not work

Answer (score 1):

The `xmlns:` attributes are special, as they are declaring namespace bindings for use elsewhere in the document.  A namespace aware XML processor will consume these attributes automatically, and use them to associate prefixed elements and attributes with the corresponding namespace URI.  You may find that if you change `setNamespaceAware(true)` to `setNamespaceAware(false)` the `xmlns` attributes are accessible, but I wouldn't recommend doing that.

Why do you want to get the value of that attribute?  You should write your code in terms of namespace URIs, and let your namespace-aware XML processor take care of resolving namespace prefixes into URIs.

Comment: I changed setNamespaceAware(true) to setNamespaceAware(false) but I could not find the value of the attribute xmlns:link.  

I need to check whether the xbrl file have the value of xmlns:link or not that is why I am trying to get the value of xmlns:link

Comment: Why do you need to check that?  In general, `xmlns:*` attributes should only be needed by your XML processor to resolve namespace prefixes to URIs.  There should be no need to retrieve them or check them yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Since **XPath 3.0** you can only query indirectly for the namespaces that have been declared with `xmlns:`.

For example, to query for the namespace of the `xmlns:xlink` declaration, you could query for any node (element or attribute) that uses the prefix `xlink:` and get the namespace from there (depending on the processor, this may be an expensive operation):

```
distinct-values((//@xlink:*, //xlink:*)/namespace-uri())
```

**Note:** alternatively, direct querying of namespace nodes might still work **up to XPath 2.0** (since then the namespace axis has been deprecated):

```
distinct-values(//namespace::xlink)
```

**Note 2:** namespace declarations are scoped. There might be several different namespace declarations for the same prefix in one XML document.